# Selenium returns random values for custom attributes

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to export image urls from the following website
https://www.list.am/category/60

On the page for an individual apartment you can see its images.

The xpath selector for images is `".//div[@id='pv']//ul/li/img"`, or css :`"div#pv ul > li > img"`. The currently active image has its attribute `src` set, while all the others have a custom attribute `'x'`, which holds the correct src to the image.

Hence, my python code looks

```
from selenium.webdriver.phantomjs import webdriver
driver = webdriver.WebDriver('path/to/driver')

url = 'url/to/any/page/from/the/list'
driver.get(url)
images = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@id='pv']//ul/li/img")
for img in images:
    print img.get_attribute('src') or img.get_attribute('x')
```

This prints correct answer only for the first item. For the others I get some random 4-digit numbers. Although chrome's developer tools show that the elements have correct values.

In chrome's console I tried

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll("div#pv ul > li > img");
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i)
{
    console.log(images[i].getAttribute('src') || images[i].getAttribute('x'));
}
```

this has printed a correct result.

Tried parsing with lxml and this also worked as expected.

Selenium gives random values for the attribute x for both Chrome and Phantomjs drivers. What is the problem?

OS: Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let me give you the *moral disclaimer*: **Somebody obviously doesn't want you scraping their web page, therefore you shouldn't be doing it.** They seem to be quite eager to make it difficult for others to do so, and there may be good reasons for that. So if you have a legitimite use for their data, ask then to provide a user friendly API for you. I'm sure they'll be happy to do so if your use of the data is fine with them.

With that in mind, and purely out of technical curiosity, and for the benefit of learning something here, let's take a closer look at that mysterious `x`:

When running `element.get_attribute('x')`, what you get is the value of the `x` *property* of that DOM object. That `x` has nothing to do with the `x` *attribute* that you see in the Chrome Dev Tools (and in the source code of the page). The *DOM property* `x` really refers to the **location of the object on the page** (notice that there's a `y` property as well.)

What you want to retrieve however is the value of the `x` *attribute*. To the best of my knowledge, the easiest way to do that with WebDriver is to use `executeScript` and the JavaScript method `getAttribute`. In Java that would look like this:

```
String x = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].getAttribute('x')", element);
```

Note that the [WebDriver W3C Standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/) recommends providing both a [Get Element Attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#get-element-attribute) as well as a [Get Element Property](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#get-element-property) API which should be consistent with the browsers internal behavior. So hopefully once all drivers implement the standard, and all client bindings expose the methods, this should be a lot clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly if you want to scrape image urls, `selenium` is a bit clumsy for such task. I would highly recommend to use [**`requests`**](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) for scraping and [**`BeautifulSoup`**](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#) for parsing and extracting.

In your case:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

response = requests.get('https://www.list.am/category/60')
html = soup(response.text, 'lxml')

imgs = html.select('td img')

for img in imgs:
    print img['src']
```

And the results:

```
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/600/16639600.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/284/15251284.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/928/12968928.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/144/12331144.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/273/16737273.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/496/14458496.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/764/15412764.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/504/15517504.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/267/11907267.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/066/11907066.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/154/16306154.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/892/11906892.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/103/11899103.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/186/12070186.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/920/12069920.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/246/16666246.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/831/12069831.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/470/12067470.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/718/12067718.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/398/12067398.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/240/12067240.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/130/12067130.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/924/12066924.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/341/16600341.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/449/8614449.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/853/16597853.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/335/16759335.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/824/13520824.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/292/16613292.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/951/13532951.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/584/17137584.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/051/17111051.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/482/17042482.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/542/17110542.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/145/16998145.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/083/17012083.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/723/17110723.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/369/17013369.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/460/17127460.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/872/16560872.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/142/11467142.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/831/17004831.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/446/16664446.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/738/14977738.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/031/16845031.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/610/17085610.jpg
//a5m4x4y3.ssl.hwcdn.net/r/502/17004502.jpg
```